# Cumulative probability with changing p

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Assuming following situation:
I have a 10 sided dice (1-10).
I´m allowed to roll the dice 10 times. For the first roll the proability to hit each number is the same 10%. For each roll consecutive roll the chance to roll a 5 is increased by 2%.
Now i want to calculate the cumulative probability to hit the 5 exactly two times in 10 tries. I know how to calculate it if the probability to hit the 5 per roll stays constant, but how do i do this if the probability changes with each roll?
For the first roll the chance to roll the 5 is 10/100, for the second roll the chance to hit the 5 is 12/100 and so on...

Comment: Welcome to math SE. have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expression.

Comment: You want the probability to have **exactly** two $5$ in $10$ rolls or the probability to have **at least** two $5$ in $10$ rolls?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I want to hit the 5 exactly two times. Sorry it wasn´t clear in my initial post, edited it.

Comment: There are $45$ possibilities to have two $5$ with $10$ rolls, and I wonder if there is a better way than brute force to find the probability you are looking for.

Comment: @AlainRemillard First, thanks for your answer but excuse me i´m a bit lost. What do you mean with 45 possibilities or better saying how is this expressed in a percentage chance?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The two $5$ could be on rolls $1$ and $2$ (first possibility), or rolls $1$ and $3$ (second possibility), $\ldots$, or on rolls $9$ and $10$ (forty-fifth possibility). There are $45$ different outcomes where you have two $5$. And brute force means evaluating each probability independently, then adding them up.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Ah understood. Thanks, now i understand what you meant with brute force!

Comment: I did it with Excel and got $0.304759153\approx30.5\%$

Answer (score 1):

I hope there is a simplier answer than this. I decided to create a speadsheet to solve the problem by brute force.

There are $45$ different outcomes where there is two $5$ on $10$ rolls.  Since the probability of getting a $5$ change with each roll of the die, 
$$P(\text{having $5$ on roll $i$}) = 0.1+0.02*(i-1)$$
I created a spreadsheet to evaluate the probability.

The number are

- the first row is the number of the roll
- the second row is the probability to have a $5$ on that roll
- the first column is just the number of the possibility, it is not use in the computation
- The second and third row are the two rolls where the $5$ appear.  E.g. possibility $30$ (row $32$), the $5$ where on roll 4 and roll 10.
- The cells D3 to M47 is the probability associated with the roll. For cell D3, the formula is `=SI(OU(D$1=$C3;D$1=$B3);D$2;1-D$2)` (my version of Excel is in french, formula might be slightly different for an english version)
- Column N is the product of the probabilities of the 10 rolls
- Finally, the green cell (N2) is the sum of all $45$ possibilities.

The answer is $0.304759152681615\approx 30.5\%$

[image]